# NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/type/descriptor/sql/IntegerTypeDescriptor$2

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an Entity:

```
    @Entity
    public class News {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String text;
    @Column(name = "scheduled_send")
    private Date scheduledSend;
    private boolean telegram;
    private boolean viber;
    private boolean facebook;
    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;
```

getters and setters

This is my config file

```
    <property name="connection.url">db url</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">30</property>

    <mapping class="package.News"/>
```

in my pom.xml I have this dependencies (hibernate version now is 5.0.1 Final):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I trying to get this entity from database I've got the error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-21146" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/type/descriptor/sql/IntegerTypeDescriptor$2
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor.getExtractor(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2611)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2594)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2423)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2418)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
    at package.NewsDao.getNewNews(NewsDao.java:51)
    at package.Sender.run(Sender.java:31)
```

Why do I got this error? I don't have any other hibernate-core jars in my project. Is there some conflict? This class already presents in my war /WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core jar

Comment: `org/hibernate/type/descriptor/sql/IntegerTypeDescriptor` is aprt of `hibernate-core`. Make sure its actually in your classpath. You can also try to upgrade the hibernate version. The latest stable version is `5.4.8.Final`

Comment: Could you edit your question with container type (eg. Tomcat, Wildfly, etc.) and those version?

Comment: tomcat 9.0.0.22M

Comment: can you try deleting your .m2 folder(maven local repo) and then rebuild the project?

Comment: Thanks. I've solved the problem.There were plenty tomcat's processes run on the machine. After killing all processes all works fine.